# Generate excel file from list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have list like this(simplified version):

```
data = [{'layer1': [{'idx': 'idx_102',
               'size': 8 },
               {'idx': 'idx_112',
               'size': 25 },
               {'idx': 'idx_142',
               'size': 10 }]
     },
    {'layer2': [{'idx': 'idx_125',
               'size': 28 },
               {'idx': 'idx_258',
               'size': 21 },
               {'idx': 'idx_658',
               'size': 12 }]
     },
    {'layer3': [{'idx': 'idx_158',
               'size': 78 }]
    }]
```

The structure of the excel file should be like this:

[image]

Can someone help, I am lost with Pandas

Comment: Is this data originating from a json? Otherwise [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) might help.

Comment: @Paul Thank you I will also check this documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested list with dict comprehensions:

```
L = [{**{'layer': k}, **x} for d in data for k, v in d.items() for x in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
    layer      idx  size
0  layer1  idx_102     8
1  layer1  idx_112    25
2  layer1  idx_142    10
3  layer2  idx_125    28
4  layer2  idx_258    21
5  layer2  idx_658    12
6  layer3  idx_158    78
```

Last if need remove duplicates:

```
df.loc[df['layer'].duplicated(), 'layer'] = ''
print (df)
    layer      idx  size
0  layer1  idx_102     8
1          idx_112    25
2          idx_142    10
3  layer2  idx_125    28
4          idx_258    21
5          idx_658    12
6  layer3  idx_158    78
```